# Without Ajax want to hit two Urls

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I have a requirement,
When a user clicks a logout button, Through third party URL we have to logout the application.When doing so it is showing there screen. 
Want to implement without  ajax in such a way that I will be able to hit third party URL after successful completion it should show my application login page. 
Note: we can't do any code change in third party URL.

Answer (score 0):

Write callback function for your logout call and define the redirect in success callback.

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'thirdparty-logout-url',
        type: 'POST',
        success : handleData
    })
} 


function handleData(data) {
    // load your page
}
```

Comment: <a href='#' onclick='getData();' /> after that I used your code.  And in handleData function i called window.location='login.jsp'. It didn't worked